# Problema de acentuação PDO mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou usando esta classe para manipular registros no MySQL usando PDO 
http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/

Porém eu insiro `ééé` e me insere `Ã©Ã©` no banco

o banco é uft8 o header do script está em uft8.

Comment: Verifica as tabelas, as vezes, o banco está Utf-8, mas as tabelas não.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tente aplicar o character set diretamente na chamada do DB assim:

```
$db = new db("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8889;dbname=mydb", charset=UTF8, "dbuser", "dbpasswd");
$db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

ou no construtor da classe:

```
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 
public function __construct($dsn, $user="", $passwd="", $options) {
  //
}
```